# Storing multiple values in Java without using arrays

Tags: java, arrays, variables, primitive-types

Take user input for 5 times, store them in a variable and display all 5 values in last. How can I do this in Java? Without using arrays, collections or database. Only single variable like `String` and `int`.

Output should look like this

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1OL94dWwAF4cDVyWG91SVZjRk0/view?pli=1

Comment: at least show us some codding.

Comment: You can do it by turning to a good book or tutorial about java, reading that stuff; learning about Java ... and then start doing it **yourself**. It might seem "efficient" to ask other people to do your homework; but the price is clearly that you need much longer to be able to come up with your own programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a needless exercise in futility, but I digress...

If you want to store them in a single string, you can do it like so:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 

String storageString = "";

while(in.hasNext()){
  storageString += in.next() + ";";
}
```

if you then input `foo bar baz` storageString will contain `foo;bar;baz;`. (`in.next()` will read the input strings to the spaces, and `in.hasNext()` returns false at the end of the line)

As more strings are input, they are appended to the storageString variable. To retrieve the strings, you can use [`String.split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)). Using this is done like so:

```
String[] strings = storageString.split(";");
```

the `strings` array which is retrieved here from the storageString variable above should have the value `["foo", "bar", "baz"]`.

I hope this helps. Using a string as storage is not optimal because JVM creates a new object every time a string is appended onto it. To get around this, use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

*EDIT: I originally had said the value of the `strings` array would be `["foo", "bar", "baz", ""]`. This is wrong. The javadoc states 'Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array'.

Comment: very nice solution.. but split() method requires an array of String. Is there any other way to retrieve ?

Comment: If you only needed to iterate through the string and output the individual strings, you could do as follows:
`

int start = 0;

for(int i =0; i <= storageString.length; i++){

  sym = storageString.charAt(i);

  if(sym == ';'){

    String out = storageString.subString(start, i-1);

    start = i;

    console.log(out);

  }

}
`

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "";
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
         s += in.nextLine();
     }
     System.out.println(s);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use Stingbuilder or StringBuffer, keep appending the some delimiter followed by the input text.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple String object and concatenate it with new value provided by user.

```
String myString = "";

// while reading from input
myString += providedValue;
```

Comment: String is a mutable object in java and thus with every modification, jvm creates a new object. so we would end up adding unnecessary objects in JVM

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala You mean **IM**mutable